# search innertext under two or more conditions

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm working on a google search from excel VBA. The text which I'm interested to extract is inside a span tag:

```
 <div class="f kv_Swb" style="white-space:nowrap">
   ...
   <span class="st">
     <span class="f">no relevant text</span>
     this is the text it matters, it has a keyword i need
   </span>
 </div>
```

There are many nested div tags.

It is a string inside an element class `st`, but outside an element class `f`. As I said, I used a VBA script like this:

```
 Dim IE as Object
 Dim doc as Object
 Dim elementA as Object
 Dim elementB as Object
 Dim TagA as Object
 Dim TagB as Object

 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Navigate "http://www.unsuspectwebpage.com/about"
 Set doc = IE.Document

 Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
   DoEvents
 Loop

 Set TagA = doc.getElementsByTagName("span")
 For Each elementA In TagA 
   Set TagB = doc.getElementsByClassName("st")
   For Each elementB In TagB
     ws.Range("A1") = ws.Range("A1") & elementB.innertext
   Next elementB
 Next elementA
```

How can I get the text which is within class `st` but outside class `f`?

Comment: you appear to be overwriting by looping a collection of elements and writing each elements inner text to the same cell. Assuming rest of code works. What is actually happening with your code? Can you show what is happening and what you were expecting?

Comment: my mistake. i don't include the objects declaration. I want to extract the text on the class "st": **this is the text it matters, it has a keyword i need.** Unfortunatelly, the html body has too many unnecessary div nodes and i want only copy the div node with the class st and paste it on my worksheet

Comment: have you tried inserting a breakpoint before the For Each loop and opening the locals window to inspect the collection TagB. I am not sure you need the outer collection if you collect all the "st" elements.

Comment: which local window do i have to open?

Comment: Ctrl and G to open in VBE ( where you code). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/locals-window

Comment: ah, you mean the Immediate Window. I put a breakpoint and write on the immediate Window "?TagA". I got a "Type mismatch" message.

Comment: No. I misquoted the shortcut. It doesn't have a fixed shortcut I don't think. You can open it under view tab in the VBE. I meant the locals window as per the link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238778(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Not a very efficient one but it should fetch you the desired content:

```
Dim elem As Object, HTML As New HTMLDocument

For Each elem In HTML.getElementsByClassName("st")
    Debug.Print Split(elem.innerText, elem.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText)(1)
Next elem
```

Output:

```
this is the text it matters, it has a keyword i need
```